# Merging range doesnt show latest items from log

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

When attempting to merge a range of revisions from trunk to release branch, the full list of items I should be able to merge doesn't show.

Today is 1st May 2014, but the calendar only shows up until 21st April 2014. The main SVN log contains items right up to today, but I can't see them in order to merge them.

[image: Tortoise SVN Merging Date Range]

These are the options I have selected:

[image: Tortoise SVN Selected Options when merging]

Answer (score 1):

Click the arrow on the `Show All` button at the bottom, there you can select `Date Range`.

The date selection control at the top of the log dialog is a simple filter: it does not fetch missing entries but only filters existing ones.

To get missing entries, use the fetch button at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks, turns out i was trying to merge from release branch to release branch, rather then from trunk to release branch. My bad...and thanks for making awesome software :)